# How to change ng-src of an image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, image

I'm trying to change the ng-src of a repeating list of images I have per album. I tried doing something janky by just increasing the size of the thumnail url but I would like a more concrete method of swapping the ng-src of my imgs to the larger url for the image. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="album.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="album.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
            <div class="bar">
                <h3>Search by ID or Title</h3><input type="text" class="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="album in albumData|filter:q" id="thumbWrapper">
                <h1>{{album.id}}</h1> 
                <h4>Title: </h4><button class="show" ng-click="showme = !showme">{{album.title}}</button>
                <div id="thumbList"ng-show="showme"class="albumContent">
                    <ul ng-controller="PhotoCtrl" id="thumbList">
                        <li ng-repeat="photo in photoData" ng-if="album.userId == photo.albumId">
                            <img id="view{{$index}}" ng-click="zoom($index)" ng-src={{photo.url}}>
                            <p ng-click="delete($index)">x</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AlbumCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums").then(function(response) {
        $scope.albumData = response.data;
        console.log($scope.albumData);
    });
});
app.controller('PhotoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos").then(function(response) {
        $scope.photoData = response.data;

    });
    $scope.delete = function(index) {

        $scope.photoData.splice(index, 1);

        var del = "/" + (index + 1);
        $http.delete("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos" + del).then(function(response) {
            console.log($scope.albumData);
        });
    };

    $scope.zoom = function(index) {
        var elem = "view" + index;
        var imageId = document.getElementById(elem);
        if(imageId.style.width == "1000px"){
        imageId.style.width = "600px";
        imageId.style.height = "600px";
        }else{
        imageId.style.width = "1000px";
        imageId.style.height = "1000px";  
        }
    };

});
```

any help is much appreciated I'm trying to learn all about $http requests and utilizing json with angular

Comment: The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change the URL, then you can pass the `photo` object to your function like this:

`<img id="view{{$index}}" ng-click="zoom(photo)" ng-src={{photo.url}}>`

Then in your `JS` code you can change the URL of that object in one line, like this:

```
$scope.zoom = function(photo) {
    photo.url = "http://your-new-url"  ;
};
```

**Update**

If you just want to toggle between `photo.url` and `photo.thumbnailUrl` in `ng-src` attribute, Then you can use this method.

`<img id="view{{$index}}" ng-click="photo.zoomed= !photo.zoomed" ng-src="{{photo.zoomed ? photo.thumbnailUrl : photo.url}}">`

and you don't need to do a function in this case :)

[DEMO (jsfiddle.net)](https://jsfiddle.net/za1zer0o/1/)

Comment: Hi I've tried something similar to this but I have an array of objects I'll need to switch the thumbnail for so i'm using it like this: $scope.zoom = function(index, obj) {
        var i = index;
        obj.url = $scope.photoData[0].url;
        
    }; but it doesn't seem to be working. any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Make sure that you wait till the `http` request done. and please, post your `HTML` code because you use `$index` that i don't use in `zoom` function.  also make sure that you open the `console`  in your browser to check if there is any errors.

Comment: there weren't any errors in the browser code atm but here is my html for the section:  <div id="thumbList"ng-show="showme"class="albumContent">
                    <ul ng-controller="PhotoCtrl" id="thumbList">
                        <li ng-repeat="photo in photoData" ng-if="album.userId == photo.albumId">
                            <img id="view{{$index}}" ng-click="zoom($index,photo)" ng-src={{photo.thumbnailUrl}}>
                            <p ng-click="delete($index)">x</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

Comment: As you use `ng-src="photo.thumbnailUrl"` in your `HTML` then you should use `obj.thumbnailUrl` instead of `obj.url` in your `zoom` function. because when button press `photo.url` updated but you don't actually use it.

Comment: here's a rewrite of how im approach the problem. I want it to switch between the thumbnails on click so i wrote this if else expression : 
        var current = false;
        if (current == false) {
            obj.thumbnailUrl = $scope.photoData[index].url;
            console.log(obj.thumbnailUrl)
            current = true; }
        else if (current == true) {
            obj.thumbnailUrl = $scope.photoData[index].url;
            console.log(obj.thumbnailUrl);
            current = false;}   issue is the console.logs come out to be the same thing not sure how to get around this

Comment: Your code is not clear for me, But i understand that you want to toggle between `.url` and `.thumbnailUrl` is n't it ?

Comment: yeah sorry it's hard to format in here =/ but yes essentially thats what i'd like to happen a toggle between both thumbnailUrl and url when i click on an individual image

Comment: @Zohranio You can see my updated, i think it'll solve it.

Comment: Hey I ran that method and i'm getting get errors in my console for each item in the photoobject =/ and the image files are not loading at all this is the error: GET file:///C:/Users/Zohra.ZOHRAN/Desktop/Album%20App/%7B%7Bphoto.zoomed net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND should I add something into my album.js file?

Comment: @Zohranio  Check the update, i add a live demo. you can check it. also re-copy the code because i update `ng-src` (Adding quotation )

Comment: hey your jsfiddle is working amazingly thanks! unfortunately I used the new <img tag with updated expression and I don't get any images to show up instead i get the row of my delete functions which still works and deletes properly

Comment: @Zohranio  Please, Can put your last version of your code in `jsfiddle,net` ?

Comment: no problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/m889k3u4/1/ Issue is I pasted my code in as is which works fine except for the recent issue we discussed, but for some reason jsfiddle breaks it?

Comment: @Zohranio You have some problems in your code . Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m889k3u4/3/

Comment: Hey I edited my code according to your js fiddle and it works! issue is the build is so slow that I have to wait like 3 mins for everything to load before i can test the zoom haha

Answer (score 1):

in the html pass the object as parameter to the zoom function

```
 <img id="view{{$index}}" ng-click="zoom($index,photo)" ng-src={{photo.url}}>
```

then in the zoom function change the url as you like

```
 $scope.zoom = function(index,obj) {

        obj.url = "whatever your url"


 };
```

Comment: Don't encourage to play with DOM inside controller, it is antipattern, If this would have the case.. I'd love to suggest OP to use `ng-style`/`ng-class`

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar did not get it. changing the image src from controller is not an anti pattern

Comment: It could have been just be achievable by changing `photo.url`, I guess you got my point...

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to read this angular [controller documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller), please specifically read **Do not use controllers to:** small section's 1st point..

Comment: hey for the obj.url would I do obj.url =  $scope.photoData.url to grab the correct indexes image url from my json object? i tried doing it as is and nothing seems to change.

Comment: post `$scope.photoData` object

Comment: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos this is what each photoData should contain trying to get it to switch from thumbnailUrl to url

Comment: this is an array. need to access by position. use `obj.url = $scope.photoData[0].url `

Comment: tried something like this:  $scope.zoom = function(index, obj) {
        var i = index;
        obj.url = $scope.photoData[i].url;
        
    }; which didn't work, but the photoData[0].url doesn't seem to work

Comment: provide a plnkr

Comment: there are so many object loading and browser getting freeze because of that

Comment: yeah is there a better way to optimize the load where it'll only load the individual album content when i click into the album button? so far it's loading around 5000 image objects throughout 100 albums =/ it's generally pretty smooth if you load it in a browser outside of plunkr or codepen or something

Comment: @sachilaranawaka hey sorry to be a bother but i'm really stuck, even without the optimizing load time is there anything I can possibly do to get the thumbnail to switch according to the correct index? should i wrap it in a foreach or something?

Comment: change the function `$scope.zoom = function(index, obj) { 
        obj.thumbnailUrl = $scope.photoData[index].url;
        
    };`

Comment: hey thanks! that worked for changing the thumbnailUrl but im trying to implement a switch between them so you can switch between the larger image and the smaller image. i've tried something like this:  var current = false;
        if (current = false) {
        obj.thumbnailUrl = $scope.photoData[index].url;
        current = true;
        }
        else if (current = true) {
            obj.thumbnailUrl = $scope.photoData[index].url;
            current = false;
        } but no luck =/

Comment: use `==` in if and else conditions

Comment: hey that makes sense forgot to use == operator but I think I'm having an issue with the obj.thumbnailUrl and the obj.url console.log to be the same thing because im setting the thumbnailUrl to url and not accounting for needing both intact to switch right?